# How to unit test this file?

Tags: jasmine, ngrx

I want to unit test this file, can you please tell how to write jasmine test for this

```
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { NavigationActionType } from 'app/core/store/actions/navigation/navigation.action';
import { NavigationService } from 'app/core/services/navigation.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationServiceEffect {
    @Effect()
    navigations$ = this.actions$
                        .ofType(NavigationActionType.TRIGGER_LOAD_NAVIGATION_ITEMS)
                        .switchMap( () => this.navigationService.load())
                        .map(data => ({ type: NavigationActionType.LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS, payload: data}));

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private navigationService: NavigationService) {}

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/testing.md

Comment: Thanks @cartant. I tried it but the control doesn't seem to reach the expect statements inside the subscribe method. E.g. if I add console.log(result) inside the subscribe method of the test case, it never prints out anything which looks like subscribe is empty. What could be the reason? Also, I didn't get this - why would you inject the class that you are testing? I am testing the Effect class so why would I inject that?

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should dispatch LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS', () => {
  runner.queue({
    type: NavigationActionType.TRIGGER_LOAD_NAVIGATION_ITEMS,
    payload: 1
  });

  navigationServiceEffect.navigations$.subscribe(result => {
    expect(result.type).toEqual(NavigationActionType.LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS)
    expect(result.payload).toEqual(1);
  });
}
```

Note you'll have to mock out the navigationService

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jasmine-marbles` that provide `hot` and `cold` observables to test the effects like this:

```
it('should dispatch LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS action', () => {
      // arrange
      const action = new TriggerLoadNavigationItems();
      const expected = cold('-a', {a: new LoadNavigationLinks({data: 'some test data'})});
      spyOn(navigationService, 'load').and.returnValue({data: 'some test data'});

      // act
      actions$ = hot('-a', {a: action});

      // assert
      expect(effects.navigations$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
```